# Using exp:playa:parents, I'd like to then access content from a different playa field at the parent

Tags: playa, parent, child

Parent channel: consultations
Has 2 child fields: patients & doctors

I am on the patient dashboard, accessing the related consultation content using:

```
{exp:playa:parents entry_id="{entry_id}" channel="consultations" show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="yes"}
```

this is working fine. Except that I want to grab the name of the doctor assigned to this consultation, so I am trying to do this:

```
Physician: {cf_consult_doctor}{title}{/cf_consult_doctor}
```

but its not showing me anything. Can I access data like this, essentially going up from a child to the parent and then down to a different child? I tried using exp:playa:siblings but its within the exp:playa:parents tag which doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, you just need to hold Playa’s hand a little so it knows which entries all of those tags belong to. You do that with Playa’s `var_prefix` param:

```
{exp:playa:parents ... var_prefix="consultation"}
  Physician:
  {consultation:cf_consult_doctor var_prefix="doctor"}
    {doctor:title}
  {/consultation:cf_consult_doctor}
{/exp:playa:parents}
```